# java program execution is suspended and I cannot step into

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging

I am working in a project in Eclipse which uses an `ExecutorService` class. Well I am not familiar with multithreading or concurrency but the problem I am facing is that when I am debugging I cannot proceed to the next method by using step into (F5). To be more specific I put a breakpoint in:

```
pool.awaitTermination(TERMINATION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

and I cannot proceed any further. The execution is suspended and if a unsupened (by pressing the suspend button) it stops to `Unsafe.park(boolean, long)` which is of java and I cannot see the code. There I cannot seem to be able to proceed any further using unsuspend or step into. The really annoying is that I can proceed using resume (F8) which leads me to the next breakpoint just like nothing happened. 
If it's of any use the arguments seems to be `TERMINATION_TIMEOUT = 100`, `TimeUnit.DAYS=6`.

I have seen other posts and I am guessing that an exception was thrown (`ThreadPoolExecutor` maybe) but the proposed solutions did not work for me or I did not manage to apply them.

Anyway any idea how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Unsafe.park is not public API, hence the source code is not shipped with your JDK. But usually you do not have to debug awaitTerminate. It simply waits for all currently running tasks of the executor service to complete. (In your case, it will wait for 100 days at most).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting breakpoint on the pool, why not set that on the `Runnable` instances you have put into the `ExecutorService` ?

If you cannot do this due to various places for submitting such `Runnable`s, you can simply Write a Runnable wrapper wrapping the real task and catch any exceptions thrown; then subclassing the `Executor` you use to actually run such an exception catching Runnable wrapper. Thus you can get all the exceptions you want.